# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1091:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
at C:\Users\salih\Desktop\JoxArea\bot.js:21:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Users\salih\Desktop\JoxArea\bot.js:20:9
```

I'm coding a discord bot but the code here gives an error. How can I fix it?

```
files.forEach(f => {
    let props = require(`./komutlar/${f}`);
    log(`Yüklenen komut: ${props.help.name}.`);
    client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
      client.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the error itself? You've just included the stacktrace which does not help much here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra `});`. You only show two opening brackets but show closing three of them.